# How do I use the Upload component with WebAPI?

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I have a Web API backend and trying to use Kendo Upload to post files to the server.
All the documentation Telerik/Progress has is just for the client side.
How do I set up the web api action to accept Kendo Upload files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's my solution after a bunch of googling and deduction:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task UploadFile()
{
    if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        var msp = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
        foreach (var content in msp.Contents.Where(x => x.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name == "\"files\""))
        {
            byte[] file = await content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            string fileName = content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('"');
        }

        //  and if you set additional data via upload event like so:
        //  uploadEvent(e: UploadEvent): void {
        //      e.data = { yourDataKey: "abcdef" };
        //  }
        string yourData = await msp.Contents.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name == "\"yourDataKey\"").ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```